# Laplace transformation and inverse Laplace question

Tags: laplace-transform

Let $$ F(s)=L\{f(t)\}$$
After a Laplace transform of f(t) the expression is : $$F(s)= \frac{2s-4}{s^2-2s+2}  $$
which equals to
$$F(s)=2\cdot\left(\frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}\right) $$
let $$x=s-1$$
Therefore
$$F(x)= \frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
My question is, if I use Inverse Laplace transformation using the table do I get $$ \cos(t)-\sin(t)$$
I ask this because I used Laplace transform from the t domain to the s domain.Now, can I go back to the $t$ domain with the $x$ domain normally ?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$F(s)=2\cdot\left(\frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}\right)$$
If you change the variable and substitute $x=s-1$ you have to substitute $s$ **on both sides**:
$$F(x+1)=2 \Bigl(\frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\Bigl)$$
$$\mathcal {L^{-1}}\{F(x+1)\}=2\mathcal {L^{-1}}\left\{ \Bigl(\frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\Bigl)\right \}$$
$$e^{-t}f(t)=2(\cos(t)-\sin(t))$$
Therefore:
$$f(t)=2e^{t}(\cos(t)-\sin(t))$$

---

So this line is not correct. Because your substitution on LHS is not correct $s=x$. When on RHS you substitute $s=x-1$.
$$F(s)=2\cdot\left(\frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}\right)$$
$$\underbrace{F(\color {red}{x})}_{x=s}=\underbrace{ \frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}}_{x=s-1}$$
It should be:
$$\underbrace{F(\color {red}{x+1})}_{x=s-1}=\underbrace{ \frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}}_{x=s-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [frequency shift property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace transform:
$$
\mathcal{L}[e^{at} f(t)] = F(s-a).
$$
So in your case, you would have
$$
F(x) = F(s-1) = \mathcal{L}[e^t f(t)]
$$

Comment: Being more specific, 
Let $$ F(s)=L\{f(t)\}$$
After a Laplace transform of f(t) the expression is : $$F(s)= \frac{2s-4}{s^2-2s+2}  $$
which equals to
$$F(s)=2* \Bigl(\frac{s-1}{(s-1^2)+1}-\frac{1}{(s-1^2)+1}\Bigl) $$
let $$x=s-1$$
Therefore 
$$F(x)= \frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
My question is, if I use Inverse Laplace transformation using the table do I get $$ cos(t)-sin(t)$$
I ask this because I used Laplace transform from the t domain to the s domain.Now, can I go back to the t domain with the x domain normally ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ F(s-\alpha) \}= e^{\alpha t}\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{F(s)\} $$

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ F(s-1) \}= e^{ t}\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{F(s)\} $$

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ 2\left( \frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}\right) \right\}= 2e^{ t}(\cos t - \sin t). $$

---

Where does the "frequency shift" property of the Laplace transform come from?:

$$\mathcal{L} \{ e^{\alpha t} f(t)\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{\alpha t} f(t) \, dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-(s-\alpha)t} f(t) \, dt = F(s-\alpha).$$